# Label single points in joint scatter subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to label all the points in each one of the four plots. I had managed to label all the points just on the last one as you can see in the figure:

[image]

However, I had tried several combinations and I can't make it work. My current script is this one. Does any body can give me hand, please?

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 8)

f, ((ax5, ax6), (ax7, ax8)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax5.scatter(large.total_tax, large.id_inf)
ax5.set_title("Large Firms")

ax6.scatter(medium.total_tax, medium.id_inf)
ax6.set_title("Medium Firms")

ax7.scatter(small.total_tax, small.id_inf)
ax7.set_title("Small Firms")

ax8.scatter(micro.total_tax, micro.id_inf)
ax8.set_title("Micro Firms")

for i, ciiu_4n1 in enumerate(micro.ciiu_4n1):
    ax8 = plt.annotate(ciiu_4n1, [micro.total_tax[i], micro.id_inf[i]])
```

Comment: Why don't add the other axes (ax5, ax6, ax7) in your for-loop?

Comment: Do the same thing what you did for ax8 for ax5, ax6, ax7 as well. Simple.

Comment: @petezurich, I tried that and it doesn't work. When I include an additional loop, for ax7 for instance. I get this error: ValueError: Image size of 1272585794x3511 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

Comment: @Bazingaa when I did that, I get this message: ValueError: Image size of 1272585794x3511 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

Comment: @PAstudilloE: Ok, try my answer below and let me know if it works. The problem could be that you are creating `ax8` multiple times whereas what you want instead is to use `ax8.annotate` and the same for other axes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another for loop to loop through the axes, and use `ax.annotate` instead to make sure you are plotting to the right axes:

```
for ax in [ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8]:
    for i, ciiu_4n1 in enumerate(micro.ciiu_4n1):
        ax.annotate(ciiu_4n1, [micro.total_tax[i], micro.id_inf[i]])
```

If each plot uses different datasets then the solution would be to do your initial loop for each axes as shown in Bazingaa's answer

Comment: I forgot to tell that every plot is from a different dataset: 
ax5 has to read the data: large.ciiu_4n1, large.total_tax[i], large.id_inf[i]
ax6 has to read the data: medium.ciiu_4n1, medium.total_tax[i], medium.id_inf[i]
ax7 has to read the data: small.ciiu_4n1, small.total_tax[i], small.id_inf[i]
ax8 has to read the data: micro.ciiu_4n1, micro.total_tax[i], micro.id_inf[i]

Comment: @PAstudilloE Can you edit that into your question? I can't really tell what you mean due to formatting of comments

Comment: I can't edit the question... but what I mean is that every plot relies on different data sets. For example, ax8 reads the information from the dataframe called 'micro', ax7 reads from the dataframe called 'small', ax6 from 'medium', and ax5 from dataframe called 'large'.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and drop a comment below if it works. It it doesn't I will delete my answer

```
for i, ciiu_4n1 in enumerate(micro.ciiu_4n1):
    ax8.annotate(ciiu_4n1, [micro.total_tax[i], micro.id_inf[i]])

for i, ciiu_4n1 in enumerate(small.ciiu_4n1):
    ax7.annotate(ciiu_4n1, [small.total_tax[i], small.id_inf[i]])

for i, ciiu_4n1 in enumerate(medium.ciiu_4n1):
    ax6.annotate(ciiu_4n1, [medium.total_tax[i], medium.id_inf[i]])

for i, ciiu_4n1 in enumerate(large.ciiu_4n1):
    ax5.annotate(ciiu_4n1, [large.total_tax[i], large.id_inf[i]])
```